# Another stopwatch using JS?

Tags: javascript, html

The code is creating a responsive page. But every time I press stop and then start again the countdown speeds up. Seconds pass like milliseconds and mins pass like seconds after about 10 or so stops and starts. What might be the issue here?
P.S. I haven't written code for the reset button.

```js
            let ms = 0;
            let secs = 0;
            let mins =0;
            let flag = true;
            var setIntID;
            watchFunction =()=> {
                if(flag){
                  ms +=4 ;
                  document.getElementById('msecs').innerText = `${ms}`;
                  if(ms == 1000){
                     ms =0;
                     secs++
                     document.getElementById('secs').innerText = `${secs}:`
                     if(secs == 60){
                        mins++;
                        document.getElementById('min').innerText = `${mins}:`;
                        secs = 0;
                      }
                }}}
                
            document.getElementById("start").addEventListener('click', function(){
                flag = true;
                var setIntID = setInterval(watchFunction,1);
                console.log(flag) //tracker
                })
    
            document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener('click', function(){
                flag = false;
                console.log(flag); //tracker
                clearInterval(setIntID);
                })
```

```html
         <div id="mainDiv">
            <div>
                <span id="min">0:</span>
                <span id="secs">0:</span>
                <span id="msecs">0</span>
                <div>
                <button id="start">start</button>
                <button id="stop">stop</button>
                <button id="reset">reset</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared `setIntID` as a local variable in `click` for the `start` button, and therefore it isn't cleared in the `click` function for the `stop`button.

```js
            let ms = 0;
            let secs = 0;
            let mins =0;
            let flag = false;
            var setIntID;
            watchFunction =()=> {
                if(flag){
                  ms +=4 ;
                  document.getElementById('msecs').innerText = `${ms}`;
                  if(ms == 1000){
                     ms =0;
                     secs++
                     document.getElementById('secs').innerText = `${secs}:`
                     if(secs == 60){
                        mins++;
                        document.getElementById('min').innerText = `${mins}:`;
                        secs = 0;
                      }
                }}}
                
            document.getElementById("start").addEventListener('click', function(){
                if (flag) return;
                flag = true;
                setIntID = setInterval(watchFunction,1);
                console.log(flag) //tracker
                })
    
            document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener('click', function(){
                flag = false;
                console.log(flag); //tracker
                clearInterval(setIntID);
                })
```

```html
         <div id="mainDiv">
            <div>
                <span id="min">0:</span>
                <span id="secs">0:</span>
                <span id="msecs">0</span>
                <div>
                <button id="start">start</button>
                <button id="stop">stop</button>
                <button id="reset">reset</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Ok so the issue with the stop button has been resolved.Thanks for that. Now as you mentioned @JMP the timer also speeds up when clicking the start button repeatedly. Is it happening because while one instance of `start` is running another is created on `click`? And more and more instances are added on repeated clicks which speed up the timer? So adding an instance counter to `start` button should solve the problem right?

Comment: Add `if (flag) return;` at the start of the function and change the initial value of `flag`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that solves the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainDiv">
        <div>
            <span id="min">0:</span>
            <span id="secs">0:</span>
            <span id="msecs">0</span>
            <div>
            <button id="start">start</button>
            <button id="stop">stop</button>
            <button id="reset">reset</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        let ms = 0;
        let secs = 0;
        let mins =0;
        let flag = true;
        var setIntID;
        var running_instance_count = 0;
        watchFunction =()=> {
            if(flag){
              ms +=4 ;
              document.getElementById('msecs').innerText = `${ms}`;
              if(ms == 1000){
                 ms =0;
                 secs++
                 document.getElementById('secs').innerText = `${secs}:`
                 if(secs == 60){
                    mins++;
                    document.getElementById('min').innerText = `${mins}:`;
                    secs = 0;
                  }
            }}}
            
        document.getElementById("start").addEventListener('click', function(){
            flag = true;
            running_instance_count++;
            if(running_instance_count == 1){
            setIntID = setInterval(watchFunction,1);}
            console.log(flag) //tracker
            })

        document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener('click', function(){
            flag = false;
            running_instance_count = 0;
            console.log(flag); //tracker
            clearInterval(setIntID);
            })

        document.getElementById('reset').addEventListener('click', function(){
            flag = false;
            ms=0; secs=0; mins=0;

            running_instance_count = 0;
            clearInterval(setIntID);
            document.getElementById('msecs').innerText = `${0}`;
            document.getElementById('secs').innerText = `${0}:`;
            document.getElementById('min').innerText = `${0}:`;

        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I see a time boost now, but on it's it's first click it's actually slow at `ms +=4` so I changed it to `ms +=10`. Also, there's no usage of the `flag` on the event handler which would help control the `setInterval()` and `clearInterval()` so that there is only one existing at a time. Everytime the "start" button was clicked in OP code there was another `setInterval()` added, therefore the time intervals combined accelerated. In the example, there's only one event handler that toggles between `setInterval()` and `clearInterval()`.

```js
let mil = 0;
let sec = 0;
let min = 0;
let flag = false;
let setIntID;

const form = document.forms.stopWatch;
const fc = form.elements;

const timer = () => {
  if (flag) {
    fc.milliseconds.value = mil += 10;
    if (mil == 1000) {
      mil = 0;
      sec++;
      if (sec < 10) sec = '0' + sec;
      fc.seconds.value = sec + ' :';
      if (sec == 60) {
        min++;
        if (min < 10) min = '0' + min;
        fc.minutes.value = min + ' :';
        sec = 0;
      }
    }
  }
}

fc.toggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (!flag) {
    flag = true;
    setIntID = setInterval(timer, 1);
    return
  }
  clearInterval(setIntID);
  flag = false;
});

form.onreset = e => {
  mil = 0;
  sec = 0; 
  min = 0;
  clearInterval(setIntID);
  flag = false;
}
```

```html
<form id="stopWatch">
  <fieldset>
    <output id="minutes">00 :</output>
    <output id="seconds">00 :</output>
    <output id="milliseconds">000</output><br>
    <button id="toggle" type='button'>Start/Stop</button>
    <button type="reset">Reset</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: I googled the minimum execution delay of `setInterval()` and found it to be 4ms. So I set the `ms` increment as 4. Hence, 1 second every 250 increments. In my original code if you click on the `start` button repeatedly for a few times then the timer speeds up a lot. Same is also true if you rotate clicks on `start` and `stop` for a few times.

Comment: Ok, IC the "start" button adds another `setInterval()` and accelerates. About the time delay, at least on my Asus AMD Ryzen 3 Win11, it's 10ms delay. When clocking at 4ms delay it takes about 3 times as long to complete a second.